# How to install CMAKE on MSYS2 or MINGW64? (all servers return 404)

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, msys2

I found this package: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
And this one too: https://packages.msys2.org/package/cmake?repo=msys&variant=x86_64

But they can't be installed with `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` and `pacman -S cmake`, all servers return 404. Here's output from the latter command: https://pastebin.com/ApsX9zpp

I tried downloading it, but it's packed with some strange .zst format that can't be opened with WinRAR/7z.

I even tried putting it into msys32\dev folder and using `pacman -U dev/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake-3.29.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst`, still with no luck.

I'm using a portable version of MSYS2.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling msys2?